# Sort a complex NSarray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an `NSArray *userInputs`, this array contains custom objects `"UserInput"`.

```
@interface UserInput :NSObject {

NSString *page_id;

@end
```

Each userInput ( `instance` of `UserInput`) belog to `BookPage`.

```
@interface BookPage: NSobject {

NSString *pagePrefix;   ( exemple : pagePrefix = @"K1")
@end
```

From each `userInput` i know to witch `BookPage` it's belong like this :

```
BookPage *bookPage = [self.book pageWithID:userInput.page_id];
```

how i can sort an `array` of `userInputs` ( `instances` of `UserInputs`) with the `pagePrefix` Key. Thanks for your answers ?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: YES and it crash, because the custom objects doon't have a property "pagePrefix"

Comment: My array does not contain "BookPage" objects, but it contain "UserInput" object

Comment: Better you put the property directly in the Custom object UserInput as you need to use that for sorting, otherwise this would become more complex

Comment: So finally got a solution or not?

Comment: no, i can't not add a property pagePrefix to a UserInput class for many reasons....

Comment: Okay, as you wish!! Tell me when you find a solution, I also wanna know a solution to this now!!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array of custom object like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pagePrefix" ascending:YES]; 
[userInputs sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: userInputs is an Array witch contain custom objects "BookPage" withc have one property : NSString *pageID; ( they don't have a property "pagePrefix")

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array like(considering your array contains strings) -

```
sortedArray = [userInput sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: My userInput array do not contain NSStrings, it contains custom objects BookPage

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a book property in the middle?

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"book.pagePrefix" ascending:YES]; 
[userInputs sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"[self.book pageWithID:input.page_id].pagePrefix" ascending:YES]; 
    [userInputs sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];  i am doing like this, but it crashes !!!!

Comment: You are not passing a key path into -initWithKey:ascending. Did my answer work? I suggest you start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html

Comment: there is not a book property in the middle, i have described all in my question

Comment: You seem to be kinda confused, what this solution is saying is right, you have a BookPage property as an intermediary. so you can do something like this if it is possible, as I've never used it like this

Comment: Yes I am kinda (not a word) confused too